# Blocking torrent access on vpn server side

Tags: vpn, openvpn, bittorrent, utorrent

we have openVPN server on our VPS, and also have a dev team who are using VPN connection to access to some resources through this VPN. But sometimes we detect a high load of our network and i think that some of them using torrent clients during VPN connection.

So is there the way to block access to torrent when developer use vpn connection to our server?

Answer (score 1):

Blocking P2P is a hard job, especially when the P2P software uses encryption.
ISPs have been trying to block torrents for a long time, with limited success.
Whatever measures you put in place can be easily bypassed by using another VPN
on top of yours.

Some ideas for stopping unsophisticated users or P2P software:

- Filter traffic and restrict access to specific ports (i.e 80, 443)
- Setup a transparent proxy that will detect/block GET to torrent trackers
  (but there are so many...)
- Setup some network detection system (i.e using Snort) to automatically detect/block torrent packets
- Use a firewall that does
  [Deep packet inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection)
  and block all references to `.torrent` and `magnet:`